# Do I need to add DLL's that are marked as dependencies to the nuget lib folder

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a package and nuspec file that I build by copying the dll for the assembly in question into a lib folder which is in the same folder as my nuspec file. This all works fine and dandy, no issues here.

I have a second package which references the first via nuget so to build it's package I followed the same process but added in a dependency element into the nuspec file. When I do my copy from release to lib it also takes the dependent dll.

Since this is marked as a dependency can I remove this from by lib folder (I want it to be downloaded via nuget, not included in the current package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing it turns out that adding a dependency does not require the dll to be in the lib. The dependency assumes it will be resolved by Nuget. This can be confirmed by creating a new package file via the nuget GUI and adding a few dependencies. Note how they do not show up in the lib folder after save.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I got your scenario exactly, but in general I could say: Depending on how you create your NuGet packages, you might not even have to specify the dependencies. Given a Visual Studio solution with the following structure:

```
* Solution1
  - Project1
    * projectfile1.csproj
      - using external libraries through NuGet
      - project reference to Project2
    * nuspecfile1.nuspec
  - Project2
    * projectfile2.csproj
    * nuspecfile2.nuspec
```

If you run `nuget pack projectfile1.csproj`, any NuGet packages included in Project1 will automatically be included as dependencies in your NuGet package, even if you haven't specified the dependency in your nuspec file. These dependencies will then also include the versions of the external libraries at the time of creation of the package.

As of [NuGet 2.5](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5#Improved_project_reference_support_for_NuGet.exe_Pack), there is also a new feature to automatically resolve dependencies between projects in the same solution. With v2.5 you can run the following command:

```
nuget pack projectfile1.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

This will also result in a NuGet dependency to Project2. And in case Project2 isn't exposed as a NuGet package (i.e. it has no nuspec file), the Project2's dll will be included as a file in Project1's NuGet package.